# ffmpeg convert and add silent audio track to an mpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I need to remove the B-Frames and also add a silent audio track to an mpeg. This is my source file (mediainfo input.mpg):

```
General
Complete name                            : input.mpg
Format                                   : MPEG-PS
File size                                : 3.88 MiB
Duration                                 : 4s 0ms
Overall bit rate                         : 8 131 Kbps
Writing library                          : encoded by TMPGEnc (ver. 2.525.64.184)

Video
ID                                       : 224 (0xE0)
Format                                   : MPEG Video
Format version                           : Version 1
Format settings, BVOP                    : Yes
Format settings, Matrix                  : Default
Format settings, GOP                     : M=3, N=9
Duration                                 : 4s 0ms
Bit rate                                 : 8 000 Kbps
Width                                    : 800 pixels
Height                                   : 600 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Frame rate                               : 30.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.556
Time code of first frame                 : 00:00:00:00
Time code source                         : Group of pictures header
GOP, Open/Closed                         : Open
GOP, Open/Closed of first frame          : Closed
Stream size                              : 3.80 MiB (98%)
Writing library                          : TMPGEnc 2.525.64.184
```

I'm trying it with:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -i input.mpg -c:v mpeg1video -b:v 8000k \
-minrate 8000k -maxrate 8000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 9 -acodec mp2 \
-ac 2 -ab 128k -ar 44100 -async 1 -shortest -y out.mpg
```

mediainfo out.mpg

```
General
Complete name                            : out.mpg
Format                                   : MPEG-PS
File size                                : 3.96 MiB
Duration                                 : 4s 23ms
Overall bit rate                         : 8 251 Kbps

Video
ID                                       : 224 (0xE0)
Format                                   : MPEG Video
Format version                           : Version 1
Format settings, BVOP                    : No
Format settings, Matrix                  : Default
Format settings, GOP                     : N=9
Duration                                 : 4s 0ms
Bit rate                                 : 8 000 Kbps
Width                                    : 800 pixels
Height                                   : 600 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Frame rate                               : 30.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.556
Time code of first frame                 : 00:00:00:00
Time code source                         : Group of pictures header
GOP, Open/Closed                         : Open
GOP, Open/Closed of first frame          : Closed
Stream size                              : 3.80 MiB (96%)

Audio
ID                                       : 192 (0xC0)
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 1
Format profile                           : Layer 2
Duration                                 : 4s 23ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Delay relative to video                  : -11ms
Stream size                              : 62.9 KiB (2%)
```

Unfortunately is the audio duration different to the video duration and there is some "Delay relative to video" of -11ms
I found in another post this option:

```
-af asetpts=PTS+0.011/TB
```

which gives me this output:

```
Audio
ID                                       : 192 (0xC0)
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 1
Format profile                           : Layer 2
Duration                                 : 3s 997ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 62.5 KiB (2%)
```

This one is close but still not my "4s 0ms" what I expected. How can I 
add a silent audio track with the "absoutly exact" duration? And do I encode the video right?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0|0:d=4.00 -i input.mpg -c:v mpeg1video -b:v 8000k \
-minrate 8000k -maxrate 8000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 9 -acodec mp2 \
-ac 2 -ab 128k -ar 44100 -async 1 -shortest -y out.mpg
```

Comment: MPEG audio is stored in frames. There are 1152 frames per channel in MP2. 153 frames gets you 3.9967 seconds of audio (what you got)  and since the codec will only output full frames, the next possibility is 4.022 seconds. To get precisely 4.00 seconds, your sampling rate should be a multiple of 144. Of the standard sampling rates, none qualify. You can minimize the over/under by picking the one with the lowest fractional part.

Comment: Correction:  There are 1152 samples per frame in MP2